# Chrome thinks two of my devices are one

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac, backup, time-machine

I have just got an iMac and I had a backup of my Macbook Pro on my time machine. I restored the iMac from this backup and everything was fine ... until I signed in to google chrome and it thinks the two devices are one. If I try to sync tabs it messes up, and logging in to my account shows them both listing 'Mac (this device)'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried logging out of Chrome and back in again? And if that didn't work, reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: Yeah. Logging out, resetting sync, logging off the mac...

Comment: You should have migrated, rather than restored. If the machine is fresh enough to not worry about losing anything done in the meantime, the best 'fix' would be to nuke & pave, then migrate as part of the setup process. [It's less painful than trying to migrate into a machine that's already been set up, or you end up with 2 users to merge.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I figured that might be the solution so I'm in the process of doing that now. What is the difference between restore and migrate? (Restore is a literal carbon copy of one machine and migrate is a new machine with just the files from another?)

Comment: In the simplest terms, a restored machine is a straight copy of the old machine including its 'identity'. A migrated machine 'knows' it's a new machine & ought to be able to handle things like this 'identity crisis' automatically.

Comment: So the migration finished, and chrome still thinks they are the same device! I chose to copy my user data and applications over.. and as soon as it finished I logged into chrome and I get `mac - this device` on both macs.

Comment: hmm... sorry, then I'm out of ideas. I'm guessing it's specifically Chrome getting confused, rather than the Mac itself.